# How do I use a Docker container inside of a vps?

Tags: docker, go, deployment, vps

I recently bought a vps after getting it recommended for my project. I want to deploy a simple golang application with one rest api endpoint to my server. I dockerized it and got it on my vps, then tried to make it a service that auto runs - here is the service file:

```
Description=Portfolio Backend

[Service]
ExecStart=/snap/bin/docker run -d -p 8080:8080 portfoliobackend
Restart=always
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/go/src/portfolio2023

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is that when I look at the status I get an error message that tells me that the specified directory is wrong:

```
    root@35:/# systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart portfoliobackend.service
root@35:/# systemctl status portfoliobackend.service
× portfoliobackend.service - Portfolio Backend
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/portfoliobackend.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-01-23 09:10:07 UTC; 3s ago
    Process: 100407 ExecStart=/snap/bin/docker run -d -p 8080:8080 portfoliobackend (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
   Main PID: 100407 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
        CPU: 1ms

Jan 23 09:10:07 35.185.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: portfoliobackend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jan 23 09:10:07 35.185.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: portfoliobackend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 23 09:10:07 35.185.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: portfoliobackend.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jan 23 09:10:07 35.185.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: Stopped Portfolio Backend.
Jan 23 09:10:07 35.185.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: portfoliobackend.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 23 09:10:07 35.185.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: portfoliobackend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 23 09:1
```

I wanted to ask if this is even the best way to go about this? Is there an alternative way that is  preferable?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does it work without the -d flag?

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way either.

Comment: And /go/src/portfolio2023 exists on the *host*? If that is a directory in the docker image use the --workdir flag for docker run instead of the systemd property (or put a WORKDIR instruction in the Dockerfile).

Answer (score 0):

1. The first thing you need to check is whether your docker is work if you run it from the command line using the command: **/snap/bin/docker run -p 8080:8080 portfoliobackend**
2. WorkingDirectory refers to your host machine, and in the above example this is clearly an unnecessary setting

As for the way of use, yes, this method is quite working, also you can compile a binary file and run it through systemctl.

In your case I would do this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Portfolio Backend
After=snap.docker.dockerd.service
Requires=snap.docker.dockerd.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=always
ExecStartPre=-/snap/bin/docker exec %n stop
ExecStartPre=-/snap/bin/docker rm %n
ExecStartPre=/snap/bin/docker pull portfoliobackend
ExecStart=/snap/bin/docker run --rm --name %n \
-p 8080:8080 \
portfoliobackend
ExecStop=/snap/bin/docker exec %n stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In this case, your container will be updated from docker registry(docker pull) before launching, and deleted after stop.
If you are not publishing your container then remove *ExecStartPre=/snap/bin/docker pull portfoliobackend* from this config.

Comment: /snap/bin/docker run -p 8080:8080 portfoliobackend works (on the vps) but when I change the service file to what you sent and reload daemon, then restart the service I get this: ```root@35:/# systemctl daemon-reload
root@35:/# systemctl restart portfoliobackend.service
Failed to restart portfoliobackend.service: Unit docker.service not found.
root@35:/# systemctl restart portfoliobackend.service```

Comment: We have a boilerplate Golang + Docker project on Github some may find useful when looking at this thread: https://github.com/IzumaNetworks/trivial-golang-k8s-deployment

Comment: This is because your docker is installed as a snap package. I changed the original message and it should work now.